# How to set data labels in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm new to `Dash` (just started today) and am trying to add some data labels to a toy data set.

My code is as follows:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

#start the application

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children='Modes of Transportation'),
                                html.Div(children = 'Explanatory text would be inserted here...'),
                                dcc.Graph(id='dash_graph',
                                    figure = {'data': [{'x':['red', 'white', 'blue'], 'y':[10, 20, 30], 'type': 'bar', 'name':'Cars'},
                                    {'x':['red', 'white', 'blue'], 'y':[5, 10, 15], 'type': 'bar', 'name':'Boats'},
                                    {'x':['red', 'white', 'blue'], 'y':[2, 4, 6], 'type': 'bar', 'name':'Trains'},                              
                                    ],

                                    'layout':{'title':'Modes of Transportation', 
                                              'xaxis':{'title':'Mode', 'type':'category'},
                                              'yaxis':{'title':'Trips per Hour'}
                                              }
                                              }),

                                dcc.Graph(id='dash_graph two',
                                    figure = {'data': [{'x':['orange', 'purple', 'blue'], 'y':[1, 2, 3], 'type': 'bar', 'name':'Mode'},],
                                    'layout':{'title':'Modes of Transportation', 'xaxis':{'title':'Mode', 'type':'category'}, 'yaxis':{'title':'Per Hour'}}})


])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```

From reading through the docs, I see that I need to set `textposition`.  I just don't know WHERE to set it.  Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation page https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/ should help out!

You'll need to add a `text` array as a peer of `x` and `y` and then alongside it set `textposition` as well.

Comment: Thank you, @nicolaskruchten.  Upon refactoring the code above into something that more closely resembles the "What About Dash?" section of https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/, I was able to very easily add text to the plot.  Thanks again!